# How can I create an Indoor Map for an Android app?

Tags: java, android, indoor-positioning-system

I'm developing an Dead Reckoning App for Android with Step Detection and Heading Estimation.

Step Detection and Heading detection work well, now I want to draw a path of my way on an indoor floor plan.

But there's the problem: I have no idea how got get a map out of the floor plan.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: which format do you have the floor plan? Can you make it a 2D or 3D model with coordinates?

Comment: PDF and JPEG. I`m not sure

Comment: Well, I have to say, this is a complicated issue. You need to use pathfinding techniques to do that. In your, maybe the easiest I can imagine, will be creating some pixels (or group of pixels) in the corners, then you can find those points, and calculate distance between each other, that way you can draw the path that you need.
Again, isn't an easy thing to do.

Comment: thank you, i just got it, if anyone is interested in the answer just contact me

Comment: @MaxKraus , I need your help regarding directions in indoor maps. Can you do that plz.

Comment: @sai What do you need?

Comment: Hi @MaxKraus, I am not able to navigate in the indoor buildings. If I choose to show directions between two points inside the building, the directions are showing outside of the building.

Comment: @sai I'm not sure what you mean, maybe you can explain what you are doing and whats the exact error.

Comment: Hi @MaxKraus, I am developing an app that requires to show path between two shops in a mall(Indoors). I am not able to draw the path inside the mall.

Comment: You need to know which dimension your map have. Try to figure out the coordinates of the pixel in the top left corner and the pixel in the down right corner.

Comment: @sai Or try to get the width and height of your Map. An example: width 200m and height 100meters. When you know your start point is (0,0), it should be easy to draw the path to (50,50).

Comment: @sai Maybe have a look at https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ . Get the ground texture of the mall and overlay your map. Then you can easily get your corner coordinates.